# Rails Best in Place: Send all Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, best-in-place

I have a table which inline-editing enabled.
However, when I update anything, e.g. the name of a person only the name of a person is sent to the controller as a parameter, but not the other things like address and age.

How can I "force" best in place to send all the parameters and not only the one which changed?

Thanks.

Comment: Why send the other parameters if you have them in db? Just update only the parameter sent.

Comment: for what? you just update it... bad smell

Comment: Yes just realized this. ^^

Comment: @OlegSobchuk I use the update function one time for inline-edit and one time for a full form-edit. And for the full-form edit I have to check if it is empty.

Comment: Any ideas how to send additional parameters on edit?